# Remove .php extensions with .htaccess without breaking DirectoryIndex

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following rewrite in my .htaccess file which removes the .php extension from files, converting for example *so.com/question.php* to *so.com/question*.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

However this also breaks the default DirectoryIndex behaviour, in which just typing the directory will redirect to the index file in the folder, e.g. *so.com/answer* displays *so.com/answer/index.php*

Simply combining the above code with `DirectoryIndex index.php` does not achieve both results.

Can someone help me combine these two functions, or rewrite the code to exclude index.php files, which would achieve the same result?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm thinking you just need to verify that the file exists prior to doing the rewrite, that way you'll leave 404 and directoryindex behaviours intact:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

(not tested)

Comment: @Timothée Groleau nice code, is there any option to remove 'index.php' for home page ?

Comment: working fine, i had little complex case, http://example.com/page.php?id=3479&name=this-is-page-name i had to convert it to http://example.com/page/?id=3479/name=this-is-page-name

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I tested and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L, QSA]
```

verify files and folder and also, add RewriteBase /

Comment: This one gives an Internal Server Error :(

Comment: strange... you add also engine on ? :)

Comment: Yes, I included `RewriteEngine On` :)

Comment: @Crsr, just as a point you don't escape `.` on the 1st arg of a cond.  :-