# Remove .php extensions with web.config on IIS7

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, web-config

I have an **.htaccess** file which removes the .php extension from files, converting for example *so.com/question.php* to *so.com/question*, and also redirecting the index file in the folder, e.g. *so.com/answer/index.php* redirects to *so.com/answer/* exactly as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9635748/310174)

I have just set up my site locally on IIS7 and need to recreate the same behaviour in a **web.config** but don't know where to start with converting/rewriting the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I have found that IIS7 and above can import Apache .htaccess rules using the **URL Rewrite module**.

1. Install the [URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads?tabid=34&g=6&i=1691) via the *Microsoft Web Platform Installer*
2. Start IIS Manager and on the left, in the Connections pane, select your required site (e.g. Default Web Site)
3. In the centre (Features View) double click **URL Rewrite**.
4. In the right panel click **Import Rules...** then paste your rules from the .htaccess file into the **Rewrite rules** box
5. Click apply in the right column.

In the specific question above the following .htaccess redirect rules

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

generate the following web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```