# .htaccess basic url rewrites

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There are a few things I want done to the URLs of my site that I cannot seem the .htaccess file to do.

1 remove file extension f.e. `example.com/file.php` should be `example.com/file`

2 remove the www. f.e. `www.example.com` should be `example.com` (I got this part to work, but I would hate it if after I put in fix and this no longer worked

3 no one should be able to see index.php at the end of root f.e. `example.com/index.php` should be `example.com`

4 my blog page should have nice urls f.e. `example.com/blog.php?article=the-name-of-article` should be `example.com/blog/the-name-of-article`

here is my current .htaccess file

### rewrite URLs

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
rewriteengine on
RewriteBase /

## Hide .php extension
## To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php

## remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]

## remove ugly part of url for blog.php
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog.php?article=$1 [QSA,L]
```

when I try to go to `blog/the-name-of-article` I get a internal server error.

Comment: 1 and 2 are more suited as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess/ and 4 as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36815217/replace-url-query-string-with-slash-for-a-friendly-url (so question may be too broad after all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the body and comments of your .htaccess it appears that I would have provided it in the past :P

Only thing wrong in your .htaccess is ordering of rules. Always have them from most specific to most generic. Have your code like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
rewriteengine on
RewriteBase /

## remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
## remove ugly part of url for blog.php
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /blog.php?article=$1 [QSA,L]

## Hide .php extension
## To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php
```

Comment: thank you, had no idea about generic to specific ruler ordering for htaccess

Answer (score 0):

To remove .php:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

see [Remove .php extensions with .htaccess without breaking DirectoryIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635524/remove-php-extensions-with-htaccess-without-breaking-directoryindex)

**EDIT**
For pretty URLs check this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/

Comment: Well I removed my way of getting rid of extensions and added yours and now the entire site will not load