# Replace URL query string with slash for a friendly URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I use the following query string

?eve=MTkzODMwMjk0OQ==

to change the content of the node's body according to the value of the value of eve.

The full URL looks like this:

http://localhost/party/event.php?eve=MTkzODMwMjk0OQ==
I would like to clean up the url to look like this instead:

http://localhost/party/event.php/eve/MTkzODMwMjk0OQ==

How can I do this with ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can even omit .php to make it more clean

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule event/eve/(.*)/ event.php?eve=$1
RewriteRule event/eve/(.*) event.php?eve=$
```

Example URL

```
  http://localhost/party/event/eve/MTkzODMwMjk0OQ/
```

will transfer to

```
  http://localhost/party/event.php?eve=MTkzODMwMjk0OQ==
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I have already tried this.

When I enter this http://localhost/party/event/eve/MTkzODMwMjk0OQ/ 

browser auto convert url into this
http://partyowl.co.in/event-detail/eve/MTkzODMwMjk0OQ/index.php