# How to convert query string value with slash using .htaccess file

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

My URL is: https://www.example.com/course.php?bid=CBSE&cid=9
and I need below url:https://www.example.com/course/CBSE/9

Comment: refere this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36815217/replace-url-query-string-with-slash-for-a-friendly-url)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

ok. This code works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^bid=(.*)&cid=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index.php https://www.example.com/course/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your last line replace with RewriteRule ^course.php https://www.example.com/course/%1/%2? [R=301,L] but after that i didnt get correct answer. When I hit the url result occur The requested URL /course/CBSE/9.php was not found on this server.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^course.php?bid=.*&cid=.*$ https://www.example.com/course/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Given code is not working Please suggest another rule

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

```
try this

    #https://www.example.com/course.php?bid=CBSE&cid=9 `#https://www.example.com/course/CBSE/9`
```

Method One:

```
#use this code for generate new url 
RewriteRule ^course/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ course.php?bid=$1&cid=$2 [NC,L]
```

Method Two :

```
RewriteRule ^course/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ course.php?bid=$1&cid=$2
```

Note :Hit Your Url course.php?bid=$1&cid=$2 to convert $i & $2 Create Dynamic Url Your Id Bases

Comment: Given code is not working Please suggest another rule

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: RewriteRule ^course/(.*)/(.*)$ course.php?bid=$1&cid=$2 This rule is working fine. But my css,js & images not working on that page: https://www.example.com/course/CBSE/9

Comment: @Sangeeta Dhiman  add site url with file link eg: http://www.yoursite.com/css/filename.css