# How to rewrite the URL with dynamic ID

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite URL based on the product ID of the product I have given in my URL. For example:

```
http://localhost/files/eeeee/product_details?pro_id=11
http://localhost/files/eeeee/product_details/12
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pro_id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^product_details\.php$ /product_details/%1? [L]
```

Comment: Go through this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468946/rewrite-rule-in-htaccess-convert-query-string-into-slashes-php , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36815217/replace-url-query-string-with-slash-for-a-friendly-url

Comment: what is your controller name?

Comment: "`/files/eeeee/product_details?pro_id=11`" - presumably that should be `/files/eeeee/product_details.php?pro_id=11`? What URL do you see in your application? Your code snippet seems to be doing the complete opposite of what you would seem to require?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?product_details/(.*?)/?$ /product_details.php?pro_id=$1 [L]
```

[image]

Comment: @vimalkumar check the snapshot its displaying the `GET` params. What issue you are facing?

Comment: I have placed your code in htaccess but its loading to

Comment: @vimalkumar where is it loading to?

Answer (score -1):

Please try:

```
RedirectMatch ^/product_details.php?pro_id=([0-9]*)$  http://example.site/product_details/$1
```

Please also refer this:
[apache-query-string-redirects](https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/)
. As this solution might require you to change the focus from mod_alias to mod_rewrite.

Comment: "from mod_alias to mod_rewrite" - `RedirectMatch` is a mod_alias directive? `RedirectMatch` also does not match against the query string, it matches the URL-path only.