# PHP Rewriting Url Not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

Here i'm facing problem with rewriting url. I'm using php(ver. above 5.0) with xampp.

My current url is
      Original url : /localhost/test/signup.php 
      redirect Url : /localhost/test/signup/

I wrote rewrite rules in htdocs

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /test/
  RewriteRule ^signup/$ signup.php
```

it's not working. I was changed httpd.conf setting also. but no use.

Comment: so you want to remove .php from url ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove .php extensions with .htaccess without breaking DirectoryIndex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635524/remove-php-extensions-with-htaccess-without-breaking-directoryindex)

Comment: like that, but in some time url is signup.php?id=4 then it will show us signup.php/4/.

Comment: you can also show like signup/4/ :)

Answer (score 0):

use below working code for me to hide .php extension.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you, but its asking create separate folder in project folder. is it possible to without folder

Comment: you can remove from http of folder name and try

Comment: RewriteBase /test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
# Resolve .php <br> file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]  <br> as per your code i was edited like above for my requirement. for example i'm clicking product.php to redirect its test/product. but it showing page not found error. its asking product folder. is it possible to avoid this. thank you

Comment: How to pass post variable through this rewrite urls.

Comment: post variable is from form you have to use get

Answer (score 0):

What error you are getting?

Meanwhile you may try with this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^(signup)$ signup.php [L]
```

for all php files:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Not only signup.php, every file need to rewrite then what is syntax for? signup rewrite need create folder. can we rewrite without folder?

Comment: Edited my answer for this scenario. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: it's working, but how to pass post variable through this url rewrite

Comment: I don't think there will be any impact on POST / GET variables. They must work as usual. Please let me know the error, if you get some issue there.

Comment: for a normal get url even if you hit this --> localhost/test/signup?id=4    It'll work.