# Remove php extension for https site using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, https, configure

I have the following to remove *.php extensions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that now I've installed an ssl certificate and its not working for subdirectories.

```
https://www.site.com WORKING(200)
https://www.site.com/example NOT WORKING (404)
https://www.site.com/example.php WORKING(200)
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: sorry for faulty answer my bad. [try this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635524/remove-php-extensions-with-htaccess-without-breaking-directoryindex)

Comment: it did not work... if I try accessing a subdirectory with https then I get 404 (page not found)

Comment: is `+FollowSymLinks` enabled by default on your host? if not use `Option +FollowSymLinks` at the begining of the file it might not make any diferrence but worth a try.

Comment: unfortunately that did not work either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying almost EVERY possible workaround, I finally found a solution.
Just needed to add this to the configuration file of my ssl site:

```
<Directory path/to/your/site>
  AllowOverride FileInfo
</Directory>
```

More info [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)