# .htaccess URL re-write - strip .php suffix

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to rewrite URLs like this:

```
http://domain.com/category.php?id=xx
```

to:

```
http://domain.com/category/?id=xx
```

Also, I want to hide the index.php. How can I achieve this with .htaccess? The following code doesn't work:

```
##REDIRECTS-START

##REDIRECTS-END

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(ADMIN.*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
### ROOT DIR TO PROJECT
RewriteRule . wallkill/index.php [L]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you done any research about this? There are many and many articles related to this.

Comment: I did, a lot. None of them helped. At least, I think they didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635524/remove-php-extensions-with-htaccess-without-breaking-directoryindex)

Comment: This breaks if the request is `/category/` (note the trailing slash). Will cause a 500 server error.

Comment: Almost solved my problem. When I visit http://domain.com/category?id=xx, it works fine, but when adding a slash after category, like this: http://domain.com/category/?id=xx it fails. Is there any possibility to cover this one too?

Comment: @JonLin Exactly, I'm getting a 500 internal server error. Do you have a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 sets of rules. The first set redirects the browser to requests without the `.php` at the end, then internally rewrites the `.php` *back*. The second rule redirects the browser to requests without the `index.php`.

So something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(.*)index\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [L,R]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Note that when you add that `/` trailing slash to the end, your relative URL base **changes**, and all your relative links will break. To fix this, either make sure all your links are absolute (start with `/` or `http://`) or add a relative base to the header of all your pages:

```
<base href="/" />
```