# Mod rewrite to remove subdirectory and file extension without breaking DirectoryIndex

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have all site pages in a subdirectory like this...

```
http://www.example.com/pages/myfile.php
```

I want the URL to look like this...

```
http://www.example.com/myfile
```

Where *both* the subdirectory called `pages` and the `.php` file extension are removed from the URL.

My latest (partial) attempt...

```
Options All -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/$1.php [NC,L]
```

However, this totally breaks `DirectoryIndex`.  When I go to `http://www.example.com/` or `http://www.example.com/foo/`, I get a 404 error instead of defaulting to `index.php` as defined by `DirectoryIndex`.

Apparently, it treats everything as a file name instead of recognizing the lack of a file name (directory) and attempting to use `index.php`.

I tried incorporating [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9635748/594235) into mine, it fixed the `DirectoryIndex` issue, but it broke everything else.

Is there a solution?  Please include a detailed explanation within your answer so I can learn where/how I was going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in root .htaccess:

```
Options All -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# add a trailing slash if pages/<uri> is a directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^/?$ pages/index.php [L]

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# if corresponding .php file exists in pages/ directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ pages/$1.php [L]

# route all requests to pages/
RewriteRule ^((?!pages/).*)$ pages/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Specifically for that case I have that `# add a trailing slash ...` rule and I have tested this case as well. You should test in Chrome dev tool or test  using curl. It will redirect `example.com/foo` to `example.com/foo/` not `example.com/pages/foo/`.

Comment: You are correct.  My browser cache was causing that last issue.