# remove .php extension from all files by.htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to remove .php extension from all url also want to redirect user to the links without file extension, if someone input url with **.php**.

change this url
`http://localhost/xyz.com/post-add.php`

to this
`http://localhost/xyz.com/post-add`

for all file is that possible with `htaccess`?

Comment: This question already asked on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635524/remove-php-extensions-with-htaccess-without-breaking-directoryindex)

Comment: Please do a search or even a google search before asking a question

Comment: i wanted to ask about redirecting users if someone enter `post-add.php` url automatically changes to `post-add`

Answer (score 0):

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```